# Modifying one dataframe appears to change another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I am new to loop in Python and just came across a weird question. I was doing some calculations on multiple dataframes, and to simplify the question, here is an illustration.

Suppose I have 3 dataframes filled with `NaN`:

```
# generate NaN entries
data = np.empty((15, 10)) 
# create dataframe
data[:] = np.nan
dfnan = pd.DataFrame(data)
df1 = dfnan
df2 = dfnan
df3 = dfnan
```

After this step, all the three dataframes give me `NaN` as expected.

But then, if I add two `for` loops in one block like below:

```
for i in range(0, 15, 1):
    df1.iloc[i] = 0

for j in range(0, 15, 1):
    df2.iloc[j] = df1.iloc[j].transform(lambda x: x+1)
```

Then all of `df1`, `df2`, and `df3` give me `1` entries. But shouldn't it be that:

`df1` filled with `0`, `df2` filled with `1` and `df3` filled with NaN (since I didn't make any change to it)?

Why is that and how I can change it to get the wanted result?

Comment: Try printing all 3 variables after the first for loop? What is the output?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Yes question solved. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assignment never copies in python. `df1`, `df2`, `df3` and `dfnan` are all references to the same object (`pd.DataFrame(data)`). This means that changes in one are reflected in the remaining ones, as they all point to the same object.

This is a great reading https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html.

To create independent copies use the `copy` method

```
dfnan = pd.DataFrame(data)
df1 = dfnan.copy()
df2 = dfnan.copy()
df3 = dfnan.copy()
```

Comment: Yes I understand now. Thank you!